# how can I get next particular date from a given date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find coming thursday date from a particular date.
For example I want 23-09-2021(Thursday) from 22-09-2021 date.
I want 30-09-2021 from 23-09-2021.
Whatever date I put, I want coming thursday date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of adding the right number of days.  Assuming you are using an American English language version of SQL Server, you can use a brute force method:

```
select dateadd(day,
               (case datename(weekday, datecol)
                   when 'Monday' then 3
                   when 'Tuesday' then 2
                   when 'Wednesday' then 1
                   when 'Thursday' then 0  -- or perhaps 7
                   when 'Friday' then 6
                   when 'Saturday' then 5
                   when 'Sunday' then 4
                end),
               datecol
              ) as the_thursday
```

If non-English support is needed, you can write locale-independent code using `format()`.

Comment: Note: Gordon's comment on "Non-English" means non American English. For those of us that are **English** English, for example, this won't actually work. (This is not me saying Gordon's answer is wrong, just that English in SQL Server terms doesn't actually mean *English*, but American.)